# google play compatibility check

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play, android-compatibility

So I am developing an android app and want to publish it to Google Play. 
The projects contains some methods that are supported only after API 13 (Like Display.GetSize() for example). 
I made my project backward compatible by going around these limitations by reading the device's OS in runtime and make decisions accordingly (for example, if the OS <13 get the screen size using another method)

even though I made the minSdk 7 in my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

everytime I launch the device chooser to choose an emulator, I see a *red cross* besides the emulator that has OS below than API 13. But the app works fine when I run it on it anyways.

THE QUESTION: 
when I upload my app to Google Play, will devices that run below API 13 be able to download my app ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red sign in emulator chooser is due to the android "Project Build Target". when you change it to the 2.1 i.e. SdkVersion=7 it will not come(the red sign).

About the Market it should not be any issue.It will definitely be available for the devices that run below API 13.